# Float is going up slower after export

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i want to multiply a float. in the unity editor everything is ok too, in the build it is going up slower all of a sudden.
i tried reimporting all assets and restart my pc but that does not help either.
I tried to build it again but that did not help.
I do not know what to do now, does anyone know how to fix this problem?
here is my build output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry5PI.png
code:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("")]
    [Header("Move Settings")]
    [Header("")]
    public float MovementSpeed = 5f;
    public float SprintSpeed = 7f;
    public float JumpForce = 5f;
    public float minJumpForce = 3f;
    [Header("")]
    [Header("Stamina Settings")]
    [Header("")]
    public float fillStamina = 1f;
    public float MaxStamina = 10000f;
    public float Stamina = 10000f;
    public Slider staminaBar;
    public GameObject SliderFill;
    public GameObject SliderB;
    [Header("")]
    [Header("Health Settings")]
    [Header("")]
    public float fillHealth = 1f;
    public float MaxHealth = 100f;
    public float Health = 100f;
    public Slider HealthBar;
    [Header("")]
    [Header("Player Settings")]
    [Header("")]
    Rigidbody2D body;
    public static PlayerController instance;
    public GameObject DeathObj;
    float horizontal;
    float vertical;



    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    private bool Sprint = false;
    //private bool ActivateLowStamina = false;
    //private bool LowStamina = false;

    
    private float move;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Stamina = MaxStamina;
        staminaBar.maxValue = MaxStamina;
        staminaBar.value = MaxStamina;
        HealthBar.maxValue = MaxHealth;
        HealthBar.value = MaxHealth;
        //ActivateLowStamina = false;
        //lowTxt.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        staminaBar.value = Stamina;
        HealthBar.value = Health;
        //var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Health < 1)
        {
            Die();
        }

        if (Stamina <= 0)
        {
            Stamina = 0;
        }
        if(Health <= 0)
        {
            Health = 0;
        }

        if (Stamina < 3000)
        {
            SliderFill.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(213, 217, 0, 255);
            SliderB.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(11, 217, 0, 47);
        }
        else
        {
            SliderFill.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(11, 217, 0, 255);
            SliderB.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(0, 255, 12, 47);
        }

        

        if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            Sprint = true;
        }

        //if(Stamina < 100)
        //{
        //    ActivateLowStamina = false;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ActivateLowStamina = true;
        //}

        //if(ActivateLowStamina == true)
        //        {
        //            lowTxt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //        }


        



        if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.x) == 0f && Stamina < MaxStamina && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) == 0f)
        {
            Stamina += fillStamina;
        }
        Health += fillHealth;




        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.001f) {
            if(Stamina > 10)
            {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            //_rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
                UseStamina(700);
            }
            else
            {
                _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, minJumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                //_rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
                UseStamina(300);
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    public void UseStamina(float amount)
    {

            if (Stamina - amount >= 0)
            {
                Stamina -= amount;
            }

        

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Sprint == true && Stamina > 10)
                    {
                     _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move * SprintSpeed, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
                    if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.x) != 0f)
                    {
                        UseStamina(10);
                    }

            
                        Sprint = false;
            

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                            if (Stamina > 10)
                            {
                                _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move * MovementSpeed, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
                                if(Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.x) != 0f)
                                {
                                    UseStamina(2f);
                                }
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move * 1f, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
                            }
                        

                    }
        //if(Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.x) != 0f)
            //{
            //Stamina -= 1;
            //}

        
    }

    

    public void Die()
    {
        if(Health < 1)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            DeathObj.SetActive(true);
            //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}
//_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * MovementSpeed, vertical * SprintSpeed);
            //transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * SprintSpeed;
            //transform.Translate(new Vector3(-3f, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
            //_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(MovementSpeed, 0);
            //_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(MovementSpeed, MovementSpeed));
//transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
                //_rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * MovementSpeed, vertical * MovementSpeed);
                //transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * 3f;

            //body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * MovementSpeed, vertical * MovementSpeed);
        //var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); ```
````

Answer (score 3):

What you experience is the typical **frame-rate dependent** code.

Every **frame** you do

```
Stamina += fillStamina;
```

and

```
Health += fillHealth;
```

However, what if on one device you have 60 **frames per second**, on another weaker device only 30?

On the weaker device it will take twice as long to raise the value.

Therefore you should use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) which is the time passed since the last frame was rendered.

By multiplying

```
X * Time.deltaTime
```

you convert a value `X` from `value per frame` into a `value per second` which is now independent of the capacity of the device and the frame-rate. Across all devices it will now always take the same effective time in seconds.

You will of course have to tweak your values but in general you would do e.g.

```
Stamina += fillStaminaPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
```

and accordingly

```
Health += fillHealthPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
```

And accordingly also for the **continous** usages

```
UseStamina(10 * Time.deltaTime);
```

and

```
UseStamina(2f * Time.deltaTime);
```

as said you might have to adjust the values since now they are more or less decided by `60` (whatever the frame-rate is).

However, for the single event calls for the jump you do **not** want/need the `Time.deltaTime` since these are no continous calls.

---

Btw instead of using `GetComponent` over and over again rather do it once in `Awake` or `Start` and store the reference in a field and later reuse it!

And instead of

```
[Header("")]
```

you should probably rather use

```
[Space]
```

;)